# Socket API will be enabled once billing is enabled

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

Can anyone let me know why I am getting this message in my login screen. 
"The socket API will be enabled for this application once billing has been enabled in the admin console".
I am building a GWT app and using Parse.com's REST API.
I cannot make out why I am getting this error.

Comment: is there anything in particular you are doing at the start of the login screen?

Answer (score 2):

To use sockets in GAE, you need to enable billing. You have two options:

- Find where you use sockets and don't use them
- Enable billing. You need a credit card, but the default daily limit is $0.00. You will never be charged unless you increase your maximum daily limit