# Getting exception while using SendGrid API Service (com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$FeatureNotEnabledException)

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using `Sendgrid` mail service in java code.I am enable to run code on localhost system and its working successfully, but when I try to run this code on google app engine project then its giving me this exception:
I am using free mail service account of Sendgrid.

Exception is:

> com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$FeatureNotEnabledException: The Socket API will be enabled for this application once billing has been enabled in the admin console.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Socket API will be enabled once billing is enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187719/socket-api-will-be-enabled-once-billing-is-enabled)

Comment: please do not duplicate questions. seems your colleage already posted the exact same: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32733556/2213940

Answer (score 0):

here is solution link,I am using SMTP API for mail service of sendgrid for free account but it will not work so,we can use WEB API.

> [sendgrid implementation without billing account in Google App Engine web project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32733556/sendgrid-implementation-without-billing-account-in-google-app-engine-web-project)