# sendgrid implementation without billing account in Google App Engine web project?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am using sendgrid APIs to send bulk emails.We have cloud application in android and web using google app engine.As we know google app engine has limited quota.So we supposed to use FREE i.e.12k/month to send emails.We have integrated it properly.If I run the code at local side i.e. localhost:888, it works but if I deploy the code and try it from there then I am getting below exception.I have created an account on sendgrid already and verified as well.

> com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$FeatureNotEnabledException: The
>   Socket API will be enabled for this application once billing has been
>   enabled in the admin console

Is it really needed to have billing account?

Answer (score 2):

You can use sendgrids [web api](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/index.html) which does not require the Socket API in App Engine.
If you want to use sendgrid's SMTP API you will have to enable billing. I would recommend using the web api though.

They have an [example](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java-sample-app/blob/master/src/com/sendgrid/SendGrid.java) i successfully use in one of my projects.